# How to display only unique child items and their count

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an ssrs report with dataset that has two fields. I grouped on field 1 and then I grouped on field 2 and now I want to just show the count of each unique items within the child group.

here is what Dataset looks like

```
Route  Driver
A      Adam
A      Adam
A      John
B      Adam
A      John

and so on
```

Here is what I'm trying to make my report look like

```
Route    Driver    Count

A

         Adam      Count of number of times Adam appears in this child group.
         John      Count of John
         Total    total for all


B      
         Adam      25
         Mike       5
         Total      total


C

         Josh       10

and so on
```

However, here it is what it looks like at the moment.

```
Route    Driver    Count

A

         Adam      count
                   count
                   count
                   count
                  continues till the number of times Adam appears




B      
         Adam      25
                   25
                   25
                   25
                   continues 25 times

         Mike       5
                    continues 5 times


C

         Josh       10 
                    continues 10 times
```

here is my design view

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm open to modifying my dataset too.

Comment: If you want to do it without a matrix like the answer below states you just need to add the scope to your expression: `Count(Fields!Driver.Value, "YourGroupingName")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a matrix, add route and driver as row groups. In the right most column enter the expression: `=count(Fields!Driver.Value)`

[image: design view]

[image: report view]

Comment: Thank you. I need to add the Drivers Total for each route as a header too.

Answer (score 1):

@Caesar Tex, to add Drivers total for each route as a header:

[image: change your report design to this]

[image: Report will look like this:]

Answer (score 0):

In your table you should have two levels of grouping - on Route and then on Driver - and no Detail row. The Route group has a header for the row title and a footer for the subtotal and the Driver group can just have the footer row, no need for a header.

Then just have your Count expression on each of the group footers.